# Determine realm changeSet fields

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list

How to determine what fields changed at RealmObject update with the basic realm adapter listener approach?

Need do have both ranges info and changed entity fields info.

```
fun notifyRecyclerViewOfChanges(changeSet: ChangeSet?) { 
   // ?
}
```

Comment: Realm 3.x, 4.x or 5.x?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.3.1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to the official `realm-android-adapters` to know how to put it together:

```
private OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener createListener() {
    return new OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(Object collection, OrderedCollectionChangeSet changeSet) {
            if (changeSet.getState() == OrderedCollectionChangeSet.State.INITIAL) { // before Realm 5.0, this is `changeSet == null`
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                return;
            }
            // For deletions, the adapter has to be notified in reverse order.
            OrderedCollectionChangeSet.Range[] deletions = changeSet.getDeletionRanges();
            for (int i = deletions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                OrderedCollectionChangeSet.Range range = deletions[i];
                notifyItemRangeRemoved(range.startIndex, range.length);
            }

            OrderedCollectionChangeSet.Range[] insertions = changeSet.getInsertionRanges();
            for (OrderedCollectionChangeSet.Range range : insertions) {
                notifyItemRangeInserted(range.startIndex, range.length);
            }

            if (!updateOnModification) {
                return;
            }

            OrderedCollectionChangeSet.Range[] modifications = changeSet.getChangeRanges();
            for (OrderedCollectionChangeSet.Range range : modifications) {
                notifyItemRangeChanged(range.startIndex, range.length);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

If you need Field-level changes, then the RealmObject needs to have its own change listener using `RealmObjectChangeListener`, and `updateOnModification` should be false (as you want to handle it in the view holder itself).

Comment: Maybe some solution to handle it not in ViewHolder but in this particular onChange listener?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure there is no reliable way to do that. It might also make sense to remove/add the object change listener in `onViewDetachedFromWindow` and `onViewAttachedToWindow` in ViewHolder.